# Why isn't this object parsed correctly?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iterator

Trying to replicate the Implicit Iterators in Python, using JavaScript my code doesn't return "Dylan", despite being a male.

Python:

```
names = [person.name for person in roster if person.male]
```

JavaScript Algorithm Test:

```
roster = {
    person: [
        {
            name: "Katie",
            male: false
        },
        {
            name: "Dylan",
            male: true
        },
        {
            name: "Alex",
            male: true
        },
        {
            name: "John",
            male: true
        }
    ]
}

var names = []
var number = -1

for(var loop = 0; loop < roster.person.length; loop++) {
    if(roster.person[loop].male == true) {
        names[number++] = roster.person[loop].name
    }
}

console.info(names)
```

*>>> [code] Returns --> ["Alex", "John"]*

Why is this? My loop goes through all the values and my if then statement is valid.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon bro (not saying that's your problem though)

Comment: Semicolons are not required at the end of each line by default in javascript.

Comment: Trusting implicit semi-colon insertion is a deadly sin. Always use semi-colons.

Comment: **@Codemonkey**, [irrelevant](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js) [nowadays](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/lib/npm.js)

Comment: I removed "json" from your question since it has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to insert an element at position `-1` of the array. See [*Increment and decrement operators*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

Either use `++number` instead of `number++`:

```
for(var loop = 0; loop < roster.person.length; loop++) {
    if(roster.person[loop].male == true) {
        names[++number] = roster.person[loop].name
    }
}
```

Or initialize the variable `number` to `0` instead of `-1`, or instead of using a variable to hold the current index value, just use `.push`, which adds a new element to the array.

Also, you don't need to explicitly compare with `true`, it suffices that the expression evaluates to `true`:

```
for (var loop = 0; loop < roster.person.length; loop++) {
    if (roster.person[loop].male) {
        names.push(roster.person[loop].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works :) But what is the difference between ++number and number++?

Comment: `number++` will evaluate the value of `number` and only *then* will increment; `++number` will *first* increment the value of the variable, and then it will evaluate its value. Thus, in your first iteration, with `++number` you get `0`, and with `number++` you get `-1`.

Comment: @EliotBall: It's the other way around bro

Comment: This is a pretty good example of where using ++number is actually useful.

Comment: @Codemonkey yeah I noticed, it's late!

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Seems simple enough. If the increment is before the variable then the increment occurs before the variable is parsed, likewise tif the increment is after the variable, it is parsed after the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning Dylan to index -1. `number` should start as 0 instead. Also, why do that manually? Just use `Array.push`:

```
var names = []

for(var loop = 0; loop < roster.person.length; loop++) {
    if(roster.person[loop].male == true) {
        names.push(roster.person[loop].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I only do JSON with APIs and I didn't know there was an `Array.push`. Based on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push I would use names.push(roster.person[loop].name, just like in your example. Thanks, that makes things easier. :)